# MultiSelect ListView steal event from parent LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have LinearLayout and inside ListView ( multi select list) with attr width and height match_parent. I need to register OnTouchListener in LinearLayout but it seems that ListView steal event. How to solve this ?

Comment: check whether linearlayout's property focusable in touch mode is true?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a custom layout extending LinearLayout like the following:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // do whatever you want with the event
        // and return true so that children don't receive it
        return true;    
    }
}
```